# Do aproximations of an ODE converge to the true value of the ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to recall a result regarding the approximation of ODEs.

Consider the ODE $x'=f(x)$ for some locally Lipshitz function $f$.

Consider the function $h_{n,t}(x) = x+f(x)*\frac{t}{n}$ and let $H_{n,t}(x) = h_{n,t}^n(x)$ where exponentiation by $n$ denotes composition of the function $n$ times. Let $G_t(x) = lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}H_{n,t}(x)$. I have the following questions:

1: Does $G_t(x)$ always exist? (eg: does the limit defining it exist)
2: Is $G_t(x)$ always a solution to the ODE?
3: What is the name of this result and where can I find a proof.

Also, I may have gotten the wrong condition on $f$, the condition might be differentiable, or maybe something else, I can't recall exactly.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method - the "global truncation error" section gives criteria under which the accumulated error is proportional to the step size, which implies the convergence you're looking for.

Comment: Note that if the solution has a veritcal asymptote then Euler's method "jumps across" it with a segment of increasingly steep slope as you decrease the step size, so your sequence of approximate solutions doesn't converge in general after the asymptote.

Comment: @Karl, if you want to expand this comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks